# BlackBerry web browser unable to connect

Tags: browser, blackberry, java-me

When I start the Browser with the default [BrowserSession](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/BrowserSession.html) object, an error keeps appearing:

> unable to connect to the selected mobile data service, please try again later
>   if this problem persists please contact your administrator.

so can anyone help me to solve this problem?

This is the line of code used to launch the browser:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Are you able to use the browser to view the web page outside of your application? It may not be an issue with your application but rather the data plan for the device.

Comment: This code works quite well in my applications. If you are on a simulator, check that MDS is running and the simulator has connected to it. Always start with checking the BlackBerry Browser can show pages from the internet. If it can, check what service book record it uses for connection. Also, this page might help: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Invoke-the-browser/ta-p/445362

Comment: yes, out side the application i can open the browser and open any url, and would u plz tell me how to run the MDS, and this link i used to write this code and it still not running, maybe its the MDS but i dont really know how to run the MDS, i,m working on the netbeans environment

Comment: oh thank u soo much Mr.Alex &Mr. Chuck for the info it was really useful, and i run the application with the MDS and it worked just fine on the simulator, but when i tried to install it on the Blackberry cellphone it poped up an error message when i open the application

it says Error starting BlackBerry $2d9000$2dTest: Module 'BlackBerry$2d9000$2dTest' attempts to access a secure API.

Comment: The BlackBerry APIs you're accessing require that the application be signed using the BlackBerry signing tool. An explanation of what APIs require signing can be found here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp and the signing tool can be found here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/signingauthority.jsp

Comment: would u plz explain this key things!! cos i'm havin a real hard time understanding it, as far as i understood is that there r some sort of public keys and private keys, and after i downloaded the tool and installed it i got a public key, but the problem is that i dont know how to use that key and can it work without the private key and how can get the private key, in the first link u sent there is a web form i should complete, is it a must that i will have to pay 20$ and will it be a 20$ for every application i make or its just this 20$ to get a key for me as a developer ??thanks for ur help.

Comment: I think it is per developer, not per application. But you must pay.

Comment: FYI, you no longer have to pay for signing keys, but you need a credit card to prove your ID. @Alex - you should put your comment in an answer so you can get rep for it!